# how to grep color for "0"

Tags: awk, grep, colors, search

Say

`echo 0 10 20 30 40| grep --color -E '0'`

I only want the first "0" to be red in color, how do I suppress the zeros from 10, 20, 30... from turning red?

Comment: `echo 0 10 20 30 40| grep --color -E '^0'` will work for this example but it's not clear whether that is actually your full requirement.

Comment: That actually worked! Just started learning grep so I am abit confused about the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html) to match a `0` that is separated from other word characters

```
echo 0 10 20 30 40| grep --color -E '\b0\b'
```

Equivalently, if your system's `grep` implementation supports it, use the `-w` (`--word-regexp`) switch to force whole-word matching

```
echo 0 10 20 30 40| grep --color -Ew '0'
```